# ¿Cómo coloco una ventana modal con background rgba encima de otros elementos como tablas e imágenes?*Hecha con HTML y Css*

Tags: css, html5, popup, background

hice un pop up con css y html, el problema es que si coloco elementos como tablas o imágenes estas desplazan el pop up y deja de verse, quiero que le pop up quede por encima de todos los elementos y no se desplace hacia abajo, eh revisado otro problemas similares con z-index pero no funciona o tal vez no lo estoy colocando de manera correcta, porque sigue el mismo problema, probé metiendo la tabla e imagen dentro de la clase "contiene-todo", pero de igual manera la imagen sigue sobresaliendo y no le afecta el background: rgba transparente.

```css
.abre-ventana {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: block;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.contiene-todo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 600ms;
}
.contiene-todo:target{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.pop-up{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.img {
    width: 40%;
    background-image: url("../Imagenes/imagen2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.contiene-Texto {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.contiene-Texto h1{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.contiene-Texto p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.Cierra-Ventana{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="../Imagenes/imagen.jpg" height="308 px" width="195 px" id="Imagen"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

            <a href="#Modal" class="abre-ventana"><button>abrir popUp</button></a>

                <div class="contiene-todo" id="Modal">

                    <div class="pop-up">
                        <div class="img"></div>
                        <div class="contiene-Texto">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                        </div>

                    <a href="#" class="Cierra-Ventana">X</a>

                    </div>

                </div>
```